# Database interaction with codeigniter and backbone.js

Tags: codeigniter, rest, backbone.js

I am trying to learn backbone.js to make a web application.This is my first time with a javascript framework and I am fairly confused with some of the stuff.

I have been developing in codeigniter for a while so I do have a understanding of the MVC architecture.

My question is how do I get the data from the backbone.js front end to my codeigniter controller and save it in the database. for example to implement a simple login/register functionality with CI and backbone, how should I proceed. If anyone can guide me step step then that would be great or point me to the right resource. Thank you.

PS: I know that I have to implement a REST api with my codeigniter but I don't know how? so if someone can provide a basic controller example it'd be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial to use the API mentioned in the above reply (by the author of the library himself)
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/